# Match multiple attribute terms in Wordpress PHP loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This seems like a simple enough problem but I'm a novice at PHP and I've been working on this for hours. I'm looping through posts in an archive and showing a different logo for each post based on a certain attribute. Here's my existing function in functions.php:

```
function show_logo() {
global $post;
$attribute_names = array( 'pa_product-type'
 );

foreach ( $attribute_names as $attribute_name ) {
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $attribute_name );
    if ( $taxonomy && ! is_wp_error( $taxonomy ) ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $attribute_name );
        $terms_array = array();

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
               if ( $term->name == 'L1' ) {
                  // Show L1 Logo
               }
               elseif ( $term->name == 'M1' ) {
                  // Show M1 Logo
               }
               elseif ( $term->name == 'H1' ) {
                  // Show H1 Logo
               }
               else {
                  $full_line = '<span>'. $term->name . '</span>';
               }
               array_push( $terms_array, $full_line );
            }

            echo implode( $terms_array );
        }
    }
  }
}
```

All I want to do is do show a different logo if the post matches multiple terms (e.g. 'L1' AND 'M1'). I have tried many very different things but I have no idea if I'm even on the right track. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do each of the clauses in the inner if/elseif/else set a value in $full_line to be pushed into the $terms_array? Maybe showing a little more code in one of those blocks would help clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly easy, I'm just not exactly sure the full context of all the data involved.

Assuming you are only showing one logo per post, here is one approach:

Right before `foreach ( $terms as $term ) {` create three boolean variables:

```
$hasL1 = false;
$hasM1 = false;
$hasH1 = false;
```

Then when one of your term names matches, instead of just showing the logo set the appropriate variable equal to true, ie `$hasL1 = true;`

After the foreach is complete, either before or after `echo implode( $terms_array );` depending on what makes sense, setup a new if/elseif/else block to decide what logo to show as follows:

```
if ($hasL1 && $hasM1 && $hasH1) { // Pick logo for all 3 }
elseif ($hasL1 && $hasM1) { // Pick logo for pair }
elseif ($hasL1 && $hasH1) { // Pick logo for pair }
elseif ($hasH1 && $hasM1) { // Pick logo for pair }
elseif ($hasL1) { // Pick logo }
elseif ($hasM1) { // Pick logo }
elseif ($hasH1) { // Pick logo }
else { // default logo }
```

Of course there are many other ways to implement this too.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I should have asked for help a lot earlier.